# Changing content of div element on main page, from another page using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

**(main.html)**

```
<div>
    Any Text Here
</div>
```

**(page2.html)**

```
<button class="home" onclick="change()">Home</button>
```

**(page2.js)**

```
function change()
{
  //From here, how can I change div content on main.html   
}
```

I want that when I click this button, the content on main.html should be changed.I have tried using localStorage also but didn't work for me...
Help me by answering this!!

Comment: How is page2.html related to main.html? Is page2.html a pop-up/tab opened by main.html, or is it a page in an iframe within main.html, or is it just another page loaded from your site, perhaps even in a different browser?

Comment: Show us what you tried using localStorage that didn't work. There is no direct way to connect one page to another with client side javascript

Comment: page2.html is related to main.html by using location.href='page2.html';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(main.html)**

```
<div id="content">
    Any Text Here
</div>
```

**(main.js)**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   const contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
   const data = sessionStorage.getItem('data');
   if(data){
       contentDiv.innerHTML = data;
   }
});
```

**(page2.html)**

```
<button class="home" onclick="change()">Home</button>
```

**(page2.js)**

```
function change()
{
  sessionStorage.setItem('data', 'some value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage stores the value permenently on client-side. So when you clicked the button it will change value forever. When next time you open the browser you will see the changed value. So to change everytime on click you have to manually replace "hello" with the text you want to see when button clicked

If you do not want to change the code everytime, you can take one input field in your page2.html and store that text in localstorage and display it in another page.

```js
<div id="page1">
    Any Text Here
    
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("page1").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("page2");
</script>
```

```html
<button id="home" class="home" onclick="change();">Home</button>

<script>
function change()
{
  //From here, how can I change div content on main.html  
 x="hello";
 localStorage.setItem("page2", x);
}
</script>
```